My Component in React JS application don't read the Headers from REST-Api - Headers is Empty
I created a Web application built with React.Js and Asp.Net core with C#.
When I do Request from Postman or Swagger I have the headers from Response.
From Swagger:

And for the postman is the same result.
In React.js I call my endpoint with the following code:
const res = await fetch(url, options);
const data = await res.json();
console.log("Head " ,res);

My console.log from inspect in app is( the headers is empty):

I do fetch my endpoint with options for Authorization but the Response have empty Headers. Why??
From libary with path node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts\fetch
And my Fetch:

My program.json
{
  "name": "linkedin",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "start": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.13.0",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.20.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "cloudinary": "^2.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mssql": "^10.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primereact": "^10.8.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^7.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "watch": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "vite": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}


Do you have any solution for my problem?

What makes you think the headers are empty? What's the result of res.headers.values().next() (or the output of res.headers.forEach(console.log) if you want to check all headers)? Also, what is the content of the options parameter?

This question is similar to: Response.header in console shows blank, but in the network tab there are headers. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Missing headers in Fetch response
